# Building Conways game of life with C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate the Neighbour near my cells, but the code works for only the middle cells and not for the corner ones, for which I can use many if loops but I wanna know how it works with for and if loops.

I tried creating extra if loops or writing like if row ==0 etc. but everything seems to give me wrong answer. btw bool[,] grid has the values of false and true. and we need to calculate how many trues and false are their in give row/ col.

```
public static int CountNeighbours(bool[,] grid, int row, int col)
        {
            int total = 0;


                for (int i = row - 1; i < row + 2; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = col - 1; j < col + 2; j++)
                    {
                        if (grid[i, j] == grid[row, col])
                        {
                            total += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

            Console.WriteLine("total neighbours for row {0} and column {1}: {2}",row,col,total-1);
            return total-1;
          }
```

The result should give perfect answer for corners and rows.

Comment: You need to write code to check whether you're in a corner or on an edge (i.e. whether `row` or `col` is `0`, etc)

Comment: I only know unperfect answer, where you check for bounds min/max using `if` =(

Comment: @Sinatr can you show it to me?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" it would be really helpful to describe what it does in some detail. ie does it throw an exception (if so include details of the exception and where it is thrown), does it come up with the wrong number, does it format your hard drive? While we might be able to guess what is actually going wrong you already have this information in front of you so no point in us guessing...

Comment: Also do you really want to be counting the number of neighbours identical to the centre cell or do you want to always return the number of live neigbours? The former seems to be a very strange way of doing things...

Comment: @Chris it works sometimes and gives wrong value, sometimes it gives Exception error and information overload. I just wanted to know how can I make just little code work where grid is boolean and row and col are the value supplied by the me.

Comment: @Chris I want to know the live neighbours, like the row has how many living neighbours which has value True (living). false = Dead, so how many Living neighbour does it has around it.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27070708/1997232) is absolutely safe, but pretty unperfect code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you count the cell itself as its own neighbour and that you don't **check the boundaries** of your grid.

Change your loop conditions like that:

```
for (int i = Math.Max(0, row - 1); i < row + 2 && i < grid.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = Math.Max(0, col - 1); j < col + 2 && j < grid.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        if (i == row && j == col) continue; // skip current cell
```

So with `Math.Max()` you ensure that you don't use a **negative** `i` or `j`, because that would lead to an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.
With `grid.GetLength()` you get the array size in the respective dimension, because using a `i` or `j` greater or equal to that length would again raise an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

And finally the last line checks that you don't count the cell in question itself.

Comment: As a minor point the OP wasn't counting the cell itself due to the fact that he had `return total-1` and that he was comparing the neighbours to the centre cell so the centre cell always added one to total that then got taken off. Your way is obviously better though. Also from comments I think the OP actually just wants to count the number of `true` neighbours so may be worth actually adding that check in too.